# Asp.net gridview pagination and rowcommand issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with page size= 10 and onrowcommand to button cliked event in gridview.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvCourseAssignments" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" ShowFooter="false" OnRowCommand="gvCourseAssignments_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvCourseAssignments_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanged="gvCourseAssignments_PageIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="gvCourseAssignments_PageIndexChanging" **PageSize="10"** Width="100%">
```

But in second page the gridview only have 2 rows.but when i clicked the button or rowcommand fired the gridview getting filled with empty rows to adjust the page size =10. but in second page has only 2 rows.

Please help.

Comment: have you put new page index when page changes

Comment: No firend,how to do it..where to put new page index..cirrently i have this code to index changed. protected void gvCourseAssignments_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            viewCourseAssignments();
        }

        protected void gvCourseAssignments_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            gvCourseAssignments.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        }

Comment: Did you bind your Gridview ??

Comment: get rid of it or not ?

Comment: Already databind.Pagination working.My issue is when I clicked a button on gridview row item on page 2,the entire gridview set to page size 10 with empty rows.I need to keep remain the gridview on page 2 even after button clicked.Currently it goes to page index 1 with empty rows. when OnrowCommand fired pageIndexChanging event not fire. protected void gvCourseAssignments_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) { try { if (e.CommandName.CompareTo("View") == 0) { hdnAss_Id_T.Value = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); } } catch (Exception ex) { } }

Comment: can you put your code here where you bind your gridview

Comment: In gridview first page is having 10 records,second page 2 records.Pagesize is 10.The problem occurs in second page with button clicked.

Comment: private void viewCourseAssignments()
{gvCourseAssignments.DataSource = ds;
gvCourseAssignments.DataBind();}

protected void gvCourseAssignments_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            viewCourseAssignments();
        }
        protected void gvCourseAssignments_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {           
            gvCourseAssignments.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        }

Comment: protected void gvCourseAssignments_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {      
                if (e.CommandName.CompareTo("View") == 0)
                {
                    hdnAss_Id_T.Value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                }
        }
        protected void gvCourseAssignments_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {}

Comment: Those are my codes.plz help.

Comment: call your viewCourseAssignments() method in Ispostback()

Comment: Already have it in (!IsPostBack) also.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void grdView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    FillGrid();
    grdView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grdView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I tried this already,but when OnrowCommand fired pageIndexChanging event not fire. protected void gvCourseAssignments_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.CommandName.CompareTo("View") == 0)
                {
                    hdnAss_Id_T.Value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                   

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

Comment: When I clicked a button on gridview row item on page 2,the entire gridview set to page size 10 with empty rows.I need to keep remain the gridview on page 2 even after button cliked.Currently it goes to page index 1.

Comment: where are you binding your gridview @page_load event or on any buttonclick

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected void gvCourseAssignments_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gvCourseAssignments.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        bindGridview();
        gvCourseAssignments1.DataBind();
    }
```

If this is done, kindly update your question with your .cs code.